# what is the use of namespace in `rosparam dump [file_name] [namespace]` command?

Tags: rosparam, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams)
I can understand the namespace use in `rosparam load [file_name] [namespace]` command in the example given, but what is the use for it in dump file generation, i tried to understand it by using double tab key, and ran this command `rosparam dump roslog.yaml /background_b` it ran successfully but when i tried to load it by `rosparam load roslog.yaml copy` it resulted in error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rosparam", line 35, in <module>
    rosparam.yamlmain()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 626, in yamlmain
    _rosparam_cmd_set_load(command, argv)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 545, in _rosparam_cmd_set_load
    paramlist = load_file(arg, default_namespace=script_resolve_name(NAME, arg2), verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 174, in load_file
    return load_str(f.read(), filename, default_namespace=default_namespace, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosparam/__init__.py", line 189, in load_str
    if NS in doc:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Any clue on what happened and what went wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283468/what-is-the-use-of-namespace-in-%60rosparam-dump-%5Bfile_name%5D-%5Bnamespace%5D%60-command?/) by [Subhassh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33830/subhassh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a look at the code ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/24c90e4b948633de7b0bcad7d6b10b159d2cf49c/tools/rosparam/src/rosparam/__init__.py#L403-L443)) it looks like this allows you to dump only a subhierarchy of parameters from the server.

Note the overlap between `rosparam get` and `rosparam dump`: they are handled by almost the same code.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0